# Using flows and a JWT (bearer token) to access an external server

Tags: jwt, swagger, salesforce

I have a requirement to access an external server using a RESTful interface from my SF org.

The server provides a complete Swagger spec.

To access the server's published functions a user must first authenticate with a userid and password. If successful, the server returns a token which is then included on the AUTHENTICATION header in all subsequent requests.

I have to retrieve a token via the login interface, store that token for future use and update the token when it expires.

I have created an external service using the provided Swagger spec. The external service uses a Named Credential which allows the use of formulas in both the HTTP header and body.

The NC is linked to an external credential that uses a Custom authentication protocol. The external credential has a single Named Principal with one Authentication Parameter. This is where I am manually storing the token that I retrieve via login using the name Bearer.

The external credential also has a Custom Header named AUTHENTICATIOH with a value of
{!$Credential.MobileAppExternalCredential.Bearer}

This set up is working as expected as long as I manually update the token. My flow is able to make use of all exposed services of the external service.

My questions are as follows:

1. Can a flow update the Named Principal's Authentication Parameter with a new token value?
2. If 1 is not possible, then where should the token be stored such that it can be retrieved for use in the AUTHENTICATION header formula.

I have looked into Custom Settings which is a non starter due to the maximum length of a text variable (tokens are longer than 255 characters).

Most posts related to this recommnend use of Custom Metatdata for the token storage but I have not found a way to reference a CMDT from the formula in the custom header.

In summary, I need a way to store and update a JWT such that it can be used in the AUTHENTICATION header.

Thanks in advance and I'm happy to provide full details as needed.